# Return different observable if payload length is < 1

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have this epic:

```
export const fetchProductsFulfilledEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_PRODUCTS_FULFILLED)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      return Observable.of(
        updateSearchResults(action.payload),
        toggleMenu(),
        updateRegion(action.payload)
      ).catch(error => Observable.of(
        fetchProductsRejected(error))
        )
    })
```

I would like to only return

```
updateSearchResults(action.payload),
toggleMenu(),
updateRegion(action.payload)
```

if `action.payload.products.length` is greater than 0, otherwise, show an alert.

Attmept:

```
export const fetchProductsFulfilledEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_PRODUCTS_FULFILLED)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      Observable.if(() => action.payload.products.length > 0,
        Observable.of(
          updateSearchResults(action.payload),
          toggleMenu(),
          updateRegion(action.payload)
        ), Observable.of(...enter alert observable here...)
      ).catch(error => Observable.of(
        fetchProductsRejected(error))
        )
    })
```

getting error:

> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide
>   an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

How do I return the `Observable.of` above, and return an observable with `showAlertDialog` if `action.payload.products.length < 1`.

Comment: Typo? You've not tested the `length`. Should it not be `action.payload.products.length > 0`?

Comment: @cartant You're right. Changed it now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a normal conditional inside the `mergeMap`?

```
export const fetchProductsFulfilledEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_PRODUCTS_FULFILLED)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      if (action.payload.products.length > 0) {
        return Observable.of(
          updateSearchResults(action.payload),
          toggleMenu(),
          updateRegion(action.payload)
        );
      } else {
        return Observable.of(
          showAlertDialog()
        );
      }
    })
```

---

As a side point, your `catch` is currently extraneous since an `Observable.of` will never throw errors:

```
.mergeMap(action => {
  return Observable.of(
    updateSearchResults(action.payload),
    toggleMenu(),
    updateRegion(action.payload)
  // this is catching errors on the above Observable but
  // this Observable will never ever throw errors
  ).catch(error => Observable.of(
    fetchProductsRejected(error)
  ))
})
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution does work :) So there doesn't really seem to be a place to catch errors in this epic?

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins if one of your action creators (eg `updateSearchResults(action.payload)`) can throw an exception, you could add handling around that but they shouldn't--that would be baddd. So this epic, as-is should not produce any errors so no error handling needed.

Comment: Makes sense! Cheers